# after compiling c++ the inode of the binary changes

Tags: c++, inode

whenever I compile a c++ source code the resulting binary gets a different inode.
I guess this is somehow related to that the old binary file is probably deleted and a new one is created. Is there a way to force the compiler to overwrite the previous binary instead in order to keep its inode the same?

Comment: And that matters, because...?

Comment: I guess you could output `temp.out` from the compiler and copy those bytes with a bash script.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks and probably there is a way to set up some post build script. I was just wondering if that can be done maybe at an earlier stage already.

Comment: Also doesn't work. The first thing codeblocks does when doing a rebuild is to delete the binary. That happens even before pre-build steps are executed. :-(